# MySQL User input to be entered at runtime

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Consider this scenario,
I have a booking table  that shows dates and different events that may be booked, and I need to write a query that will display all bookings made within two specific dates given.

Is there any way that the two dates can be user-inputted during the runtime of the query?

Comment: You might need HTML and JS to format the date entered and pass it to backend Query in MySQL

Comment: Are you running this query actually within MySQL Workbench (as your tags suggest), or from a command line? Either way, it doesn't look like it's possible

Comment: @DaveyBoy I am using MySQL-Workbench,

Comment: @Zalgawi - in that case, you can't. Workbench is just for SQL design, DB admin etc. If you want user interaction, you're going to have to write a front end (even it's a bash script which passes variables via STDIN, and then uses those within a MySQL command line call. The closest you can get in Workbench is to use variables and change them in the query each time